# FileSystemWatcher - Como pegar o usuário que modificou arquivo C#

Tags: c#, .net, sistema-de-arquivos

Desenvolvi uma aplicação que monitora os eventos no filesystem usando a classe `FileSystemWatcher` e gostaria de deixar instalado no servidor de arquivos acontece que preciso registrar o usuário que acessou o arquivo pela rede.

**Observação:** localmente sei que posso usar:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

**ou**

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                 new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
```

e pela rede?

Comment: que tal fazer um registro dos usuarios num BD. Quando for alterar o arquivo pedir confirmação de usuário, senha e confirmado passar info da hora e nome do usuário pra uma outra tabela. Fica inviável?

Comment: Fala aí. Putz cara inviabiliza muito. Deve existir uma forma, o próprio SO registra estes eventos quando a auditoria de arquivos é habilitada. :(

Answer (score 0):

No título você diz usuário que alterou, mas na pergunta você diz o usuário que acessou.

Caso queira o usuário que acessou, você não conseguirá pelas propriedades do arquivo. Provavelmente terá que implementar um controle de acessos aos arquivos.

Caso queira o último usuário que alterou, você terá dificuldades quando o usuário for de outro domínio.

Caso esteja no mesmo domínio, tente o seguinte código:

```
var usr = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(path).GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
```

ou

```
var usr = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(path).GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
```

Comment: Fala ai @Felipe Grossi... Usando o método `SecurityIdentifier` retorna o id e usando  'NTAccount' retorna algo assim "BUILTIN\Administradores".

Comment: Encontrei esta outra forma no stackoverflow gringo: string Owner = File.GetAccessControl("path").GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();

Comment: @ThiagoCeconelo lendo este artigo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016279/objectsecurity-getowner-returns-group-rather-than-user tive o seguinte questionamento: Como você tem acesso de administrador de domínio, o resultado pode ser inesperado. Peça para um usuário "comum" alterar o documento e rode o programa novamente para ver se o resultado sai conforme você deseja.

Comment: Cara funcionou... pelo menos em partes ... Quando o arquivo é deletado já não consigo usar esta função. :( . Cara como será que o SO registra isso no event viewer? Tem idéia?

Comment: Pelo que estou entendendo, você precisaria seguir por um caminho de controlador de acessos... mas como esta desenvolvendo na mão, vamos ver os recursos disponíveis. Para verificar o histórico de exclusão, tem como utilizar o event viewer sim, porém você terá que habilitar o audit dos arquivos. De uma olhada nesse artigo: https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/301640/how-to-set--view--change--or-remove-auditing-for-a-file-or-folder-in-w

Comment: Pois é .. Agora como ou melhor que classe ou dll que o SO usa para registrar estes eventos associando os mesmos ao usuário? Cara complicado ...rsrs

Comment: Vejo que você vai ter que dividir seu problema em 2 partes:
1) Alteração / Criação do arquivo (que entendo você já ter o domínio do assunto)
2) Log de exclusão do arquivo (que você ainda não conseguiu dominar o assunto)
Vou dar mais uma pesquisada para ver se consigo te ajudar com o log da exclusão dos arquivos...

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei, para resolver o problema do arquivo deletado o caminho mais fácil e que provavelmente será lento... é habilitando o audit do windows: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399 e buscando pela classe System.Diagnostics.EventLog os eventos logados no event viewer.